# Wrong iPhone launch image displayed when iPhone app is launched on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, default.png

I have developed a straight iPhone/iPod Touch app. 
A launch image is implemented for Retina displays as well as the lower resolution of the former generation devices. 
Those images are displayed properly on the iPhone simulator as well as on several iPhone an iPod Touch devices.

However, since some days, when launched on an iPad (1) or iPad simulator one of the other images within the app is shown.

Apparently the image that is displayed wrongly, is one of two amongst ca. 70 images within the app. Those two images happen to be either
1. the first image in my xcode project groups hierarchy. 
-or-
2. the first image in my project in alphabetical order.

I did not yet find a pattern of when 1. or 2. happens, so when the first image in the project's hierarchy of groups is taken or when the first in alphabetical order is taken. But it seems to be one of these two files only.

Any idea what I probably did wrong so that a wrong image is picked as launch image of this iPhone-only app whenever it is launched on an iPad?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Hermann

Comment: Does your app's `Info.plist` file have a [`UILaunchImageFile`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) key?

Comment: There may be differences depending on the version of iOS on the iPad. iOS 3.2 doesn't know about retina display images.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting an image named Default.png into Xcode. That's all, just drag it in. Xcode recognizes any picture named Default.png as the loading image. That should make it work.

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention that before. I did that already. However, I did that in parallel to defining the other launch images in plist.info or on the project's summary pane in xcode 4. Would you suggest only to include a default.png and getting rid of the proper definitions of the other scales?

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on Jack's answer - you can indeed use an image named Default.png which will automatically be used as a launch image for your app.

However,you can also customise the launch image for particular hardware and device orientations by using images of a particular size and name - for example, a 768x1004 pixel image named `Default-Portrait~ipad.png` added to your project will be automatically used as the launch image when you launch the app on an iPad in portrait orientation.

The use of these customised images is highly recommended, as it allows the launch image to be sized appropriately for the different shapes of screen (i.e. iPhone and iPad), and allows high resolution launch images to be used on Retina display devices.

For a list of these sizes and image names, see [this page](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840/). The items of interest are the ones beginning with "Default"

Comment: Thanks for the answer and that link. I will try that although I do have my doubts. (Will report back the result of course.)  - The key point here is that my App is NOT an iPad app and is not (yet) intended to be. It is a native iPhone app that just happens to behave strange when being launched on an iPad.

Comment: All right, seems to be working now.

Now I named the *.png files as suggested AND provided exactly these names, "Default.png" etc., in the info.plist.

Apparently both has to be done. 

Thanks again. 

My understanding so far was that you can either follow the naming conventions or use any name but provide the name in the info.plist in the appropriate fields.

Comment: @Hermann: I'm glad you got it working! You're right though - you should be able to using the naming conventions _or_ the Info.plist file, either should work alone.

Comment: Guys unfortunately this was not the solution. I am still getting the some wrong graphic displayed only when the iPhone app runs on an iPad. 

That ist the only reason why I did not accept any answer. Although the answers were correct at such, they did not solve the issue. ... I am new to this. Let me know if this is 'over correct' or something.

Answer (score 0):

All iPhone apps have a splash screen, or what Apple refers to as a “launch image”. It is the screen that is displayed immediately after you press your app’s icon on the home screen, while the app icons are sweeping away and your app is zooming into view.

Some apps opt not to display a splash screen and go for a black screen, which is the default behaviour when you create an app. Others display a wireframe of the app’s interface in order to look like it is loading faster. See Apple’s native apps such as Clock and Camera for good examples of this. The most common use of the splash screen (especially in games) is to present a company or game logo, as we do in Addicus:

Apple has made it so easy to set your splash screen that you don’t even need a single line of code to do it. Why, you don’t even need to change a setting. Here’s how to set your splash screen it in just 2 steps:

1. Add a file to your project’s Resource folder called Default.png.
2. There is no step 2. Take this time to reflect on how good life is.

And that’s it. Run your app and your splash screen will zoom into glorious view.

A couple of things to watch out for when working with splash screens:

Whatever image you give it will be scaled to fill the 320×480 resolution of the iPhone, so ideally you would use a 320×480-sized image.

If your iPhone app is running in landscape mode, you need to rotate the splash screen you use. For example, our splash screen is rotated 90 degrees to the right in the above image.

- See more at: http://getsetgames.com/tag/launch-image/#sthash.GEXwuzsf.dpuf

Comment: That is all right, but does not provide an answer to the question.